# Replit's Enviornment Variables - undefined on save

Tags: environment-variables, bots, replit

I've been using Replit.io as a means of hosting a bot I built. As a part of that I have to store some API keys / secrets / or ENV vars. The built in tools for this: https://docs.replit.com/tutorials/storing-secrets-and-history
are super helpful, and work, but I recently got hung up where these variables were returning as undefined. How can this be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Simple refresh of the page after adding and saving the variables then waiting a minute or two before re-starting the bot itself.